# Система Android закрывает мою службу переднего плана ForegroundService

Tags: android, service

Всем привет.

Пишу приложение под Android >=12, в котором использую ForegroundService для получения координат пользователя и синхронизации их с сервером.

У меня еще нет ни одного размещенного где-либо приложения (я начинающий).

Когда я тестирую свое приложение, устанавливая его из Android Studio, всё отлично - приложение устанавливается, служба работает, координаты сохраняются на сервер.

Но когда я создал свою подпись для приложения и установил его на смартфон путем скачивания с сервера, возникли следующие неприятные моменты:

1. При установке приложения появляется предупреждение о том, что разработчик неизвестен. И пользователю настоятельно не рекомендуется устанавливать это приложение.
2. Моя ForegroundService служба отключается периодически в определенное время. И не перезапускается, несмотря на включенную пользователем настройку "Автозапуск".
3. После закрытия работающей службы, например стандартным приложением MIUI "Безопасность" при очистке памяти, и последующего автоматического запуска службы (пользователем включена настройка "Автозапуск") перестало работать определение координат по GPS (FusedLocationProviderClient).

После курения интернета, наткнулся на [пост](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14293528/22009266), в котором говорится как правильно организовать ForegroundService, чтобы он не прибивался системой. Выполнив `adb shell dumpsys > tmp.txt`, выяснил, что FS оформлен правильно, всё функционирует должным образом.

```
    Proc #18: prcp   F/S/FGS  ---N  t: 0 8656:com.example.my/u0a368 (fg-service)
```

НО:

```
package: com.example.my
    Historical Process Exit for uid=10368
        ApplicationExitInfo #0:
          timestamp=2023-06-01 09:43:52.752 pid=7411 realUid=10368 packageUid=10368 definingUid=10368 user=0
          process=com.example.my reason=10 (USER REQUESTED) subreason=21 (FORCE STOP) status=0
          importance=125 pss=99MB rss=217MB description=stop com.example.my due to from process:com.android.vending state=empty trace=null
```

Это при том, что, естественно, сам я ничего не завершал.

И меня напрягает вот это: `due to from process:com.android.vending`.

В связи с этим прошу подсказать и направить по верному пути:

А. Я правильно понимаю, что эти сюрпризы стали происходить по причине отсутствия меня и моего приложения на Google Play?

Б. Если я размещу приложение в Rustore и нигде больше, это решит мою проблему?

В. Если я заблуждаюсь в вопросах А и Б, прошу направить по правильному пути.

**Обновление от 04.06.2023**

Вчера я отключил Play защиту в Play-маркете. Моя служба больше никем не прибивается. Работает уже больше суток.

Comment: Заставить фоновую службу работать постоянно - почти невыполнимая задача. Наличие в магазине не поможет и никак не повлияет. Помочь может составление для юзера подробной инструкции по настройке приложения в системе - типа режим энергосбережения не распространять на приложение, не ограничивать фоновые процессы etc. При этом инструкция может (и будет) отличаться для разных производителей телефонов и разных версий ОС и прошивок от производителей.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, контроль активности установлен пользователем на "Нет ограничений".  К тому же com.kms.free как-то работает при тех же равных условиях.

Comment: Хм... Попробуйте проверить ваше предположение о том, что дело в наличии приложения в магазине, отключив в настройках магазина защиту. Вроде как оно в настройках маркета находится, внутри самого приложения.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да вчера отключил Play защиту и в течение суток уже служба работает. Теперь остается вопрос: поможет ли размещение приложения в Rustore (что-то подсказывает, что не особо поможет)?  И, если не поможет, то как в нынешних условиях новому разработчику разместить приложение в Google Play?

Comment: В RuStore не поможет, т.к. гугл прибивает приложение. В маркет выложить можно. Надо создать акк российский, оплатив его зарубежной картой. Главное убедиться что при оплате будет выбрана нужная страна, т. е. РФ а не страна выпустившая карту. Иначе документы у вас не РФ потребуют и аккаунт вы не сможете создать

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, благодарю за информацию.